# adding a ListBoxItem in a ListBox in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, string, listbox, listboxitem

I know that:

```
String test = "test";
ListBox.Items.Add(test);
```

or

```
String test = "test";
int index = 1;
ListBox.Items.Insert(index, String);
```

adds the String in a ListBox, but I want to insert ListBoxItem, how to?
previously I learn that

```
var contentToString = (String)ListBoxItem.Content;
```

simply converts ListBoxItem to String, but I couldn't do the opposite to convert String to ListBoxItem

Comment: Is this asp.net or winforms?

Comment: @DaniloVulović: an ASP.NET ListBox has no content property.

Comment: There is no ListBoxItem in winforms!

Comment: to be specific, I'm writing a Windows 8 metro apps. I use C# and XAML.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try this:

```
ListBoxItem itm = new ListBoxItem();
itm.Content = "some text";

listbox.Items.Add(itm);
```

listbox is name for ListBox.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like that

```
ListBox1.Items.Insert(0,new ListItem("ITEM 1", "Value"))
```

Comment: not working, there is no ListItem in Windows 8 metro app with C# and XAML

Answer (score 1):

Your object will always be in a ListBoxItem, the ListBox will generate one for you if you don't add it explicitly. To get the ListBoxItem you use:

```
var listboxitem = (ListBoxItem)listbox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(myItem);
```