# how to update listbox from another window

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, window

I've got a AddWindow to add new client, the MainWindow (which is always showed) and I want to send the information from Addwindow to ListBox in MainWindow (I mean i need to add new item to listbox).

Someone knows how can I do that?

Comment: Is your question [how to add item to ListBox](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13267657/1997232) ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us your code and explain what you have tried so far, so we don't present solutions you already tried as answers. Thanks.

Comment: I was trying to use constructor overloading but it's not the good way because when i'm doing new instance of MainWindow I'm losing listbox's items which were already exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with events of that object like this :

```
 public partial class AddWindow : Window
{
    public AddWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Check != null)
            Check(TextBox.Text);
    }


    public event Action<string> Check;


}
```

and in main window

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();  

    }


    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddWindow popup = new AddWindow();
        popup.Check += popup_Check;
        popup.Show();

    }

    void popup_Check(string obj)
    {
        ListBox.Items.Add(obj);
    }
}
```