# How can I append a newly created control to another control in c#

Tags: c#, xaml

I am still a newbie to VS, C# and XAML. I have this XAML code

```
<ListBox Background="Black" x:Name="ListBox1" Width="900" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="{Binding ElementName=ListBox1, Path=Width}"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Now I want to create and add another child control to the `ListBox` control using c#. I use this code below to create a `ListBoxItem` control

```
ListBoxItem li = new ListBoxItem();
li.Background = Brushes.White;
li.Width = 150;
li.Height = 200;
Thickness margin = li.Margin;
margin.Left = 5;
margin.Right = 5;
margin.Top = 5;
margin.Bottom = 5;
li.Margin = margin;
li.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
li.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
```

Then I also use this code to append the newly created `ListBoxItem` to the `ListBox` control

```
ListBox1.Controls.Add(li);
```

But its not working. I don't know what am getting wrong

Comment: is it UWP WinForms or Xamarin?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adding a ListBoxItem in a ListBox in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267657/adding-a-listboxitem-in-a-listbox-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(li);
```