# I want to append newly created controls to a ListBoxItem control using c#

Tags: c#, xaml

I am still a newbie to VS, C# and XAML. So I got this code from my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54186259/how-can-i-append-a-newly-created-control-to-another-control-in-c-sharp) on how to add child Control to a listBox.

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(li);
```

I try to use the same pattern to add child Control to my ListBoxItem control, but its not working, so I used this method, it didn't throw any error but my app is taking the whole year to load

```
li.Children.Add(img);
```

I don't know if its the right way to do this.

**My Question:** I want to add an `Image` control to a newly created `ListBoxItem`. This is my code below

```
foreach (var imgPath in filePaths)
{
    WrapPanel li = new WrapPanel();
    li.Width = 150;
    li.Height = 200;
    Thickness margin = li.Margin;
    margin.Left = 5;
    margin.Right = 5;
    margin.Top = 5;
    margin.Bottom = 5;
    li.Margin = margin;
    li.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
    li.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    Image img = new Image();
    img.Width = 150;
    img.Height = 150;
    img.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
    img.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
    BitmapImage imgSrc = new BitmapImage();
    imgSrc.BeginInit();
    imgSrc.UriSource = new Uri(imgPath, UriKind.Relative);
    imgSrc.EndInit();
    img.Source = imgSrc;
    li.Children.Add(img); // This is where my problem is
    ListBox1.Items.Add(li);
}
```

And I will also want to create a `TextBlock` control also and add it to the newly created `ListBoxItem`

```
TextBlock textBlk = new TextBlock();
textBlk.Width = 150;
textBlk.Height = 50;
textBlk.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
textBlk.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
```

So I will also like to know if I will add the `TextBlock` control with the same code as to add the `Image`. And I want to do all this in C#

**My thoughts:** Why don't MS make C# as easy as JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this code and worked

```
// Codebehind 
foreach (var imgPath in filePaths)
{
    var li = new WrapPanel
    {
        Width = 150,
        Height = 200,
        Margin = new Thickness(5),
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
        HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
        Background = Brushes.DarkBlue
    };

    var img = new Image
    {
        Width = 150,
        Height = 150,
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
        HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
        Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imgPath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)) // this is the main difference with your version 
    };

    li.Children.Add(img);

    var textBlk = new TextBlock
    {
        Width = 150,
        Height = 50,
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom,
        HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
        Background = Brushes.Aqua,
        Text = "Test text"
    };

    li.Children.Add(textBlk);

    ListBox1.Items.Add(li);
}
```

View

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox1" />
```